# Easy way to distribute ruby script

Tags: ruby, rubygems, distribute

I have a bunch of ruby scripts in a folder which is added to `$PATH` and I think that some of them might be usefult to others. So I want to distribute them and the only 'good' way I know is rubygems (gem containing only binary), it has a very useful advantage of versioning, but also a drawback of initialization time (sometimes it takes some seconds before script starts to run). Are there alternatives?

Comment: What do you mean by "initialization time"?

Comment: @Jeremy: run `cat $(which rake)` — rubygems is initialized and gem containing binary is found before script is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gem is good enought for this. I use gem for this purposes as it is very convenient to intall and update.

Answer (score 1):

Gems are built for this. I'm not sure what you think a gem is, but RubyGems is a repository like PEAR for PHP, aptitude for ubuntu, or CPAN for perl, except they contain ruby libraries.

There is no extra overhead or "initialization time" added to your ruby libraries by making them gems. RubyGems simply installs your library - it doesn't do anything else.

Comment: There is overhead — requiring rubygems and searching for gem containing script

Comment: @tig have you benchmarked this to determine if it's an actual issue? The time is almost definitely negligible. If it actually is, you could simply skip rubygems and manually require the file. This way you get the ease of distribution with RG but you don't have the overhead of the path search.

Comment: I did not benchmark it, but noticed its presence (that is why I know how rubygems bin works :), overhead is not constant in time, first run is slow, further runs are fast). What do you mean by skipping rubygems? I want to distribute executable script like `rake` or `rails`.

Answer (score 0):

Gems are fine for this kind of Ruby script.

To quickly generate a new gem, try out [`bundle gem`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler).

To quickly distribute gems without using rubygems.org, and in a way that could work for private deployment, check out the idea for [microgems](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2011/microgems-five-minute-rubygems/).

If you still don't think you need to wrap these in gems, you can simply add the executable bit to your scripts, add shebang lines for ruby, and remove the `.rb` extension. Then share your script files with whoever wants them.